# How to install the lustre client on Ubuntu nodes?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ubuntu-20.04, lustre

I am trying to install the lustre clients on Unbuntu 20.04 nodes I have in GCP. Im using linux kernel version `5.15.0-1021-gcp`.

I'm trying to install the client with the following code:

```
cd /home/apps/
mkdir lustre
git clone git://git.whamcloud.com/fs/lustre-release.git
cd lustre-release
git checkout 2.15.0
sh autogen.sh
./configure --prefix=/home/apps/lustre --disable-server --enable-client ## doesnt run! Fails at ./configures with error message "error: Run make config in /lib/modules/5.15.0-1021-gcp/build"
make debs
```

The configure step fails with an error about running `make config` in `/lib/modules/5.15.0-1021-gcp/build`. I tried running `make config` in `/lib/modules/5.15.0-1021-gcp/build` but was asked to input some values that I was unsure of.

I also tried downloading the deb package of the client software at
`https://downloads.whamcloud.com/public/lustre/lustre-2.15.0/ubuntu2004/client/lustre-client-modules-5.4.0-96-generic_2.15.0-1_amd64.deb`. However this is for the wrong linux kernel and I'm not sure what env variables need to be set for this package.

Anyone know how to install the client modules for lustre on Ubuntu?

Comment: My solution was the DDN exascaler which supports Ubuntu as a client.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the kernel sources or kernel-devel package that exactly match the kernel that you are installing on. This should also include the .config file that describes all of the options used when building your kernel.

Alternately, you could try a pre-built package, but it isn't clear if this will install on your kernel or not.

https://build.whamcloud.com/job/lustre-b2_15/40/arch=x86_64,build_type=client,distro=ubuntu2204,ib_stack=inkernel/